# Why do Stack Overflow Careers 2.0 profile stats show 0's despite views?

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow, jobs

On the [stackoverflow careers](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/) homepage (when I'm logged in), it says:

### your profile

Public views 0
Employer views 0
Search hits 0
Email inquiries from employers 0
Email responses to employers 0

Assuming "public views" means how many times [my public page](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/dantup) has been viewed, I don't understand why it's 0 - I've sent the link to a few people for feedback, and I know it's been viewed.

Are the stats broken, or have I misunderstood?

Comment: Probably cached. Don't know for sure though.

Comment: It's been like this for many days :(

Comment: Ok, now I'm confused. Now it's showing 1! However, there have *definitely* been many views earlier this week!

Comment: That doesn't sound like caching...

Comment: I got confused - the "Edit" page shows "1 views, 1 today, 1 week, 1 month", but the homepage (careers.stackoverflow.com) still shows 0 for them all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whoopsie-daisy. It seems we lost our tracking pixels somewhere along the way.  They're back now, so those numbers will start updating again.  I also fixed the discrepancy between the homepage and the CV edit page.  Thanks for the report!

Comment: Someone probably needed the pixels elsewhere. We should order a new batch.

Comment: Cool, thanks. (PS. How did this slip through testing ;-))

Comment: @Danny: What-ing?

Comment: Dunno - I heard it on a webcast once and thought I could be clever by quoting it. Didn't expect to be called on it ;o(