# Careers View/Search counters are all 0

Tags: support, jobs

My home page on Careers shows all 0's for views/search hits on my profile.

### your profile

Public views 0
Employer views 0
Search hits 0
Email inquiries from employers 0
Email responses to employers 0

On my profile page, it also shows 0 views all time, last month, last week, etc.

[image: Profile Views]

I don't think this is possibly true.  I'm not actively looking and it's not public, but it is employer searchable and I can't quite believe that it hasn't been viewed even once ever.  And 0 search hits, seems even less likely. It hasn't even come up on a list by an employer even once?

This sounds like [Why do Stack Overflow Careers 2.0 profile stats show 0's despite views?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81818/why-do-stack-overflow-careers-2-0-profile-stats-show-0s-despite-views) but that is marked as resolved and is over a year old.

Comment: Mine are *not* at 0, but my profile is public. Also, note that the stats only go back 1 month. I see no reason why profiles would not be viewed even when found, as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The second set of view you listed from your profile page are you public profile views only.  In order for those counts to increase, your profile must be set to public (with a public route specified) AND people must visit your public profile.  If your profile is not public, and you have not told anyone about your public profile, I think it's safe to expect those numbers to stay at 0.

As for your search hits and employer views, I can confirm there have been no hits on your profile so far.  That's not to say you don't have a good profile, you do.  There are some things you could do to make it better suited for our search system however, most of which you can find out by clicking on your profile completeness report on the right hand side bar.  Don't be alarmed if your completeness score is not capped out, we do not expect it to be and even mine is not capped.  The only time we use completeness in search at all is for sort order in the trial search.  The completeness score is there to encourage you to fill out more information on your profile, which generally improves your rankings in our candidate search product.

Comment: OK, so that makes sense on the second view, but I'm still surprised at 0 for search hits.  A low number, sure, but 0? Is it your hypothesis that because I have a (relatively) low completeness score, that it's not coming up on the first page of otherwise relevant searches?

Comment: Yes that is my hypothesis, your profile would be getting search hits, but we only count search hits when your profile is **shown** to employers in the list, and employer views are only when they click on your profile from that list.  If you match the search, but are never shown on the page, we don't count it as a hit.