# Bug on careers 2.0 with profile views count

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

This is similar [Why do Stack Overflow Careers 2.0 profile stats show 0's despite views?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81818/why-do-stack-overflow-careers-2-0-profile-stats-show-0s-despite-views) but apparently it's not fixed or it's not working as intended.

On the my-profile page I see this for profile view count:

[image]

If I do this: Click Employer View -> Privacy Settings
I see this:

[image]

Which seems closer since I know my profile has been viewed. But even this still does not seem right, since yesterday I had 16 views for the month, yet today it says I have had 3 views; which *should* mean 19 views for the month. (Unless my maths is wrong, but I was pretty sure 16+3 = 19)...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a bug.  The view on this page is counting all of your profile views instead of just the public profile views.  If you hit the homepage while logged in and look on the right hand side, you'll see numbers for Employer views, Search hits and Public views.  If you add all of those numbers together, it should add up to that number.  This will be fixed sometime today or tomorrow.

Answer (score 6):

This has been fixed and should make its way live shortly. Nick is correct: the privacy page was not filtering the view information correctly (actually it wasn't filtering it at all).